# How many permutations of a linear equation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> How many strictly positive integer solutions does the equation
>   $x_1+x_2+···+x_n = k$ have? (Hint: Consider the equation $y_1+y_2+· · ·+y_n = k−n$ with variables $y_i \ge 0$.)

I believe the second equation represents the first, but fixes $k$ as a positive integer. How can I show this rigorously?

In turn, this means there are $n-1+k-n$ total elements and $n-1$ elements chosen. I will then compute the binomial coefficient with these values. Is this correct?

Comment: let $y_i = x_i - 1$

Comment: So there are (k-1) choose (k-n) ways?

Comment: I think it's $(k-1)$ choose $(n-1)$.   I always remember this in a silly way.  I'm walking past $n$ baskets and taking $k-n$ objects from them, so I have $(k-1)$ actions, namely $(k-n)$ actions of "pick up an object" and $(n-1)$ actions of move to the next basket.  The only choice is which of those $(k-1)$ actions will be the $(n-1)$ "move on" actions.  Here, $y_i$ is the number of objects you take from basket $i$.

Comment: Are they not the same?

Comment: oops!  you're right!

Comment: The result is correct. Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/648383/139123, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/657515/139123, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115236/139123